# Saving Images in Golang from Base64 String

Tags: base64, png

I am using a Wacom signature set to capture a signature in JS as a Base64 string. Then I send this Base64 string to my Golang server and save it into DB.
When I then want to save this Base64 String as an image I always get an error "Bad png".
All converters can open the Base64 Strings without problems. 
Here is my function and Base64 String as an example.

```
func saveImageTest() 
{
im1 := "" //Link to the string is below
idx := strings.Index(im1, ";base64,")
if idx < 0 {
    fmt.Println("InvalidImage")
}
ImageType := im1[11:idx]
fmt.Println(ImageType)
unbased, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(im1)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Cannot decode b64")
}
    r := bytes.NewReader(unbased)

    im, err := png.Decode(r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Bad png")
    }

    f, err := os.OpenFile("example.png", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0777)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Cannot open file")
    }
    png.Encode(f, im)
```

}

[Link to the Base64 String](https://pastebin.com/0kbEEfE9)
[Test signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtEQQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You must start `DecodeString` at `idx + 8` (after ";base64,").